# java.lang.NullPointerException for android.widget.EditText.addTextChangedListener

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

Currently i am having a

> java.lang.NullPointerException error for
>   android.widget.EditText.addTextChangedListener

What i am trying to do is letting the user, key in a text/string into a "EditText" field. Once the code detect a change in the "EditText" field, it will get text/string from the "EditText" field and automatic display it out into a field name "tv".

i have search online for a solution but none work for me

below is what i have tried

what i found so far online suggested putting a final in front of the EditText which does not work for me

```
 final EditText filename1 = (EditText)findViewById(container.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Below is the code which the LogCat  feedback the error

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
                    EditText filename1 = (EditText) container.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

                    filename1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){

                    }
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                        SeeThroughTextView tv = new SeeThroughTextView(getActivity());                      
                        tv.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(1000, 1000));
                        tv.setText(s);
                        tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 60);
                        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.view_bg);                       
                    }
                });     
                return filename1;       
         }
  }
```

Full Java Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{

    int counter;

    Button button1, button2, button3, button4;
    ImageView image;
    EditText filename1, filename2;
    FrameLayout digit;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);      
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        filename1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        filename2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);




        NumberPicker np1 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.np1);
        NumberPicker np2 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.np2);
        np1.setMaxValue(9);
        np1.setMinValue(0);
        np1.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
        np1.setOnValueChangedListener( new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {

            }
        });

        np2.setMaxValue(9);
        np2.setMinValue(0);
        np2.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
        np2.setOnValueChangedListener( new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {

            }
        });


        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }


    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment
    {


        public PlaceholderFragment()
        {
        }




        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

                    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
                    EditText filename1 = (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

                    filename1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){

                    }
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {



                        SeeThroughTextView tv = new SeeThroughTextView(getActivity());
                        tv.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(1000, 1000));
                        tv.setText(s);
                        tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 60);
                        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.view_bg);


                    }
                });

                return layout;
        }
    }

    final static class SeeThroughTextView extends TextView
    {
        Bitmap mMaskBitmap;
        Canvas mMaskCanvas;
        Paint mPaint;

        Drawable mBackground;
        Bitmap mBackgroundBitmap;
        Canvas mBackgroundCanvas;
        private boolean mSetBoundsOnSizeAvailable = false;

        public SeeThroughTextView(Context context)
        {
            super(context);

            mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_OUT));
            super.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            super.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        }

        @Override
        @Deprecated
        public void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable bg)
        {
            mBackground = bg;
            int w = bg.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int h = bg.getIntrinsicHeight();


            if (w == -1 || h == -1)
            {
                w = getWidth();
                h = getHeight();
            }


            if (w == 0 || h == 0)
            {
                mSetBoundsOnSizeAvailable = true;
                return;
            }

            mBackground.setBounds(100, 100, w, h);
            invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        public void setBackgroundColor(int color)
        {
            setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(color));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
        {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            mBackgroundBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mBackgroundCanvas = new Canvas(mBackgroundBitmap);
            mMaskBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mMaskCanvas = new Canvas(mMaskBitmap);

            if (mSetBoundsOnSizeAvailable)
            {

                mBackground.setBounds(0, 0, w, h);
                mSetBoundsOnSizeAvailable = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {

            mBackground.draw(mBackgroundCanvas);
            mMaskCanvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
            super.onDraw(mMaskCanvas);
            mBackgroundCanvas.drawBitmap(mMaskBitmap,100, 100, mPaint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBackgroundBitmap, 0.f, 0.f, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Full XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:background="@drawable/activity_bg"
            app:context="com.example.crossover.MainActivity"
            app:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="28dp" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:text="Button" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/np1"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/np2"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:width="50dip" />

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/np2"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button6"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:width="50dip" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/np1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:maxLength="9"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/np1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:singleLine="true" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `container.findViewById()` will not work, you will need to inflate your layout in which your 'EditText' is present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inflate your `xml` layout inside your `onCreateView(...)` method and get the reference of your `id's.`

```
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, container,false);
EditText filename1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Comment: Dear Sir,
Thanks for the Help. 
As per Sir Satyen Udenshi say i am trying it out.
but i aint sure if the "yourlayout" is it refer to the layout file name which hold the container

Comment: where you have define `editText1` id? Do you have any `.xml` file which contains `EditText`?

Comment: i have define the editText1 in my activity_main.xml ( the only xml file at the moment). in my activity_main.xml there is another editText call editText2.

Comment: add your whole code in your question so that it can be easily picked up by us to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `inflate` your layout into a `View` in `onCreateView()` method, you can so something like below

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflating view layout
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.you, container, false);
     EditText filename1 = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

                filename1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){

                }
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    SeeThroughTextView tv = new SeeThroughTextView(getActivity());                      
                    tv.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(1000, 1000));
                    tv.setText(s);
                    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 60);
                    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.view_bg);                       
                }
            });     
            return layout;   
}
```

Comment: Hi sir
for the below line the R.layout.you
does the you refer to the layout file name which holder the container?

Comment: See container here refers to Viewgroup i.e our parent layout, here in this case it would refer to layout of your activity in which the fragment is added hope you get its and is your problem solved ??

Comment: in a way yes but it have create another issue. once i inflate the layout. my button on the left seen to have duplicated itself and appear inside the container.